# Dolphin service menu to run konsole command with copied data in working directory

Tags: download, konsole, dolphin, youtube-dl, servicemenu

I would like to combine these two elements that I already use:

- Konsole terminal running a `yt-dlp` command in order to download from a copied link (like `konsole -e yt-dlp 8 %u`)
- A Dolphin service menu to open Konsole at a specific location (`konsole --workdir %f`)

I would like a Dolphin service menu to open Konsole at a specific location AND run the `yt-dlp` command.

[image]

I need that when I quickly want to run that command on a USB-stick or other removable device, without the need to manually copy its location or of copying the file there after download, etc.

How to combine the `%f` and/or `%u` parameters here? After `--workdir` they are referring to the directory that is open in Dolphin, and after `yt-dlp` they are referring to the copied download link, so that a line like `Exec=konsole --workdir -e yt-dlp 8 %u` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xclip` is the key (it may need to be installed)

The correct line should be like:

```
Exec=konsole --workdir %f -e yt-dlp <some_options> $(xclip -o)
```

(As usual, writing a question helps one find the answer!)